# How to make TL-WN722N work in Kali?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, debian, wireless-adapter

I have checked several forums, websites, and github repositories for a solution however none of them worked for me. There's several links that I wanted to post but apparently I can't post more then 2 links at a time. I acknowledge that there are posts like this in this forums but the answer didn't work for me.

However I haven't tried these links ([link3](https://www.udoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn722n-usb-wireless-adapter.1873/), [link4](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29013337/Driver-For-tp-link-wn722n-v2-for-kali-2-0.html)) out because I saw people are having trouble making the USB wireless adapter work in Kali. I'm not familiar with Ubuntu but I doubt Ubuntu and Debian has the same procedure in setting the adapter. Again, Kali is Debian linux and I just want to figure how how to make my adapter work. I've tried 'apt-get install firmware-atheros' and 'apt-get update'. It still hasn't worked. When I type in 'lsusb', I can see my usb wireless adapter there. But my adapter is not glowing which means it's not working (as said in the instructions that came with the box).

I have Kali in Virtual Box together with VB Extensions, if in case anyone wants to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 versions of that specific adapter. There is the old version which does support packet injection and the newer version which doesn't. If you look on the back of the adapter next to the barcode you should see the version number. If yours says 'V2.0' then there is nothing you can do. It has been hard coded to not support packet injection. You will have to buy a version 1 or just get a completely different one.

I spent ages digging trying to find this answer because I had the same problem as you

Comment: Can you give me a reference that says that "it has been hard coded to not support packet injection"? I've looked into the internet and I can't see anyone selling v1 anymore.. in my country. However, I may have to see other people's answers because I've notice some people were able to get their adapter working.

Comment: I cant give you a reference because I bought mine 3-4 months ago which is when I found out about the two versions. Sorry bud. You might as well return it back to the seller and get a different adapter

Answer (score 0):

The TL-WN722N support monitor mode with a driver provided by mfruba. [Link](https://github.com/mfruba/kernel/tree/master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink).
worked fine for me, and im using Kali 2.0 sana.